# Jolt - Array into Key Value Pairs

Tags: java, json, jolt

I am trying to convert this input below to the expected output using Jolt

Here's my Input:

```
[
  [
    "station_name",
    "station_longname"
  ],
  [
    "10 Mile Brook Dam Water Level Daily Value, South W",
    "10 Mile Brook Dam Water Level Daily Value, South West Region"
  ]
]
```

I am trying to convert it into this output -

```
{
  "station_name": "10 Mile Brook Dam Water Level Daily Value, South W",
  "station_longname": "10 Mile Brook Dam Water Level Daily Value, South West Region"
}
```

I tried using this Jolt -

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[&1]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But it came back like this -

```
[
  [
    "station_name",
    "10 Mile Brook Dam Water Level Daily Value, South W"
  ],
  [
    "station_longname",
    "10 Mile Brook Dam Water Level Daily Value, South West Region"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation specs such as

```json
[
  { // dissipate each component of the respective arrays
    // to their respective object
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&.comp&1"
      }
    }
  },
  { // match components within each object
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@comp1": "@comp0"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thank you. what's comp mean?

Comment: You're welcome @DrewNicolette that's nothing but abbreviation of component(of the arrays)